# wrong behaviour of m2crypto compared to openssl

Tags: python, m2crypto, smime

I have to consolidate and possibly rewrite a bunch of bash scripts that verify that incoming smime messages are valid (i.e. encrypted with company's private key and signed a certain set of public keys)

This bunch of bash is going to be replaced by a small application, written possibly in Python with the help of M2Crypto.

Until now, the decryption part is really going well, but I'm having a problem with signature verification.

I need to write python code that will replace this single bash line

```
 openssl smime -verify -in to_verify.txt -CAfile signer_pubkey.pem -out verified.txt
```

The content of to_verify.txt is the "usual" multipart/signed p7, that can have the signature attached or not.

The previous command exits with 0 when the verification is successfull and extract the content from the smime envelope.

now, back on python, taken from m2crypto examples:

```
import os
from M2Crypto import BIO, Rand, SMIME, X509
cert_dir = '/home/niphlod/certs'
doc_dir = '/home/niphlod/datastore'

signer = os.path.join(cert_dir, 'signer_pubkey.pem')
letter = os.path.join(doc_dir,'out_decrypt.txt')

# Instantiate an SMIME object.
s = SMIME.SMIME()

# Load the signer's cert. 
x509 = X509.load_cert(signer)
sk = X509.X509_Stack()
sk.push(x509)
s.set_x509_stack(sk)

# Load the signer's CA cert. They're all self-signed, hence the following
st = X509.X509_Store()
st.load_info(signer)
s.set_x509_store(st)

# Load the data, verify it.
p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7(letter)
v = s.verify(p7)
print v
print data
print data.read()
```

Well.... surprise, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m2crypto_verify.py", line 28, in <module>
    v = s.verify(p7)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/M2Crypto/SMIME.py", line 215, in verify
    blob = m2.pkcs7_verify0(p7, self.x509_stack._ptr(), self.x509_store._ptr(), flags)
M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7_Error: no content
```

Openssl is reading, extracting and verifying this files correctly, but how can m2crypto report that there is no content ?

BUMP: noone interested in this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around a similar problem using M2Crypto v0.17 by changing the line:

```
 v= s.verify(p7)
```

to

```
 v = s.verify(p7,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer is right.

```
    v = s.verify(p7,data)
```

The verify() method needs to compare the two parts of the signed message (the plain text against the encrypted one).

This function takes a few argument as mentioned in the [M2Crypto doc](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/). It calls openssl PKCS7_verify method documented in [OpenSSL's doc](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html). It's unfortunate that M2Crypto's tutorial contains erroneous default values (at least with the v0.20.1 in my environment).

Answer (score 0):

This is the mechanism I'm using for doing S/Mime verification with M2Crypto

```
# Load the data
#
try:
  p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7( letter )
except SMIME.SMIME_Error, e:
  print 'Error: could not load {file} because {error}'.format(file=letter,error=e)
  sys.exit()

# Verify the data
#
try:
  if data is not None:
    v = s.verify(p7, data)
  else:
    v = s.verify(p7)
  if v:
    print 'Client signature verified'
except SMIME.SMIME_Error, e:
  print 'Error: message verification failed %s' % e
```